# Why do Ashkenazim respond בְּרִיךְ הוּא in kaddish?

Tags: tefilla, kaddish, nusach-ashkenaz

Is קֻדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא a translation of הקדוש ברוך הוא? At any rate both expressions are one phrase.
Why then in kaddish do we reply with בריך הוא when someone says שְׁמֵהּ דְּקֻדְשָׁא, בְּרִיךְ הוּא or שְׁמֵהּ דְּקֻדְשָׁא.
[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11514/answering-brich-hu-to-the-kaddish-before-shemone-esrei-at-maariv) is related and Double AA in a comment quotes Taz OC 56 sk 3 who clearly reports בריך הוא as a response.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7873/759

Comment: Definitely a duplicate -- see the answers there for a full explanation, in particular the discussion in the Aruch HaShulchan.

Comment: Not a duplicate imho. Just very closely related.

Comment: The answers there might answer this question, actually, but they should be answering a slightly different question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Magen Avraham] says that the custom is to say brich hu with the  Chazan so that he wouldn't stop there (like the Rama requires and unlike the Mechaber who says that one **should** stop there).

In other words, one is saying (in Aramaic) "...should be praised the name of The Holy One Blessed is He *who is* above all blessings, praise, etc."

Now, people made a mistake and interupt the Chazan with "Brich hu" which goes against the Rama.

Comment: I was going to question (ask for a source for) your translation, but I asked it as [a separate question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14878) instead.

Comment: Actually, I think we are saying "May blessed, praised, lauded....be the name of the Holy One (Blessed be He) above all other blessings..." meaning that we are slightly going off topic to separately bless HaShem, since we mentioned Him as the Holy One (Blessed be he), and continue on with how blessed and praised His name should be.

Comment: Never mind, heading over to @msh210's question now.

Comment: Nevertheless, Shmuel Brill and Seth J, we are still splitting up the phrase "קֻדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא". 

Curiouser's answer to this question (judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7873/759) What should be said after "sh'mei d'kudsha, brich hu" in Kaddish? brings the Aruch HaShulchan which satisifies me as an answer here. I suggest the question starts from a different point but the answer is the same. Thanks @Double AA for drawing attention to it.