# Parsing the "Yisbarach..." sentence in kaddish

Tags: kaddish, text

[Kaddish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish) reads (in part):

> יתברך וישתבח ויתפאר ויתרמם ויתנשא ויתהדר ויתעלה ויתהלל שמה דקודשא בריך הוא לעלא מן כל ברכתא ושירתא תשבחתא ונחמתא דאמירן בעלמא

How do we parse this? Here are some possibilities, though maybe it's none of these:

1. "May the name of the holy one (blessed be he beyond all blessings, songs, etc.) be blessed, praised, etc." ("לעלא" refers back to "בריך הוא".)
2. "May the name of the holy one (blessed be he) be blessed, praised, etc. beyond all blessings, songs, etc." ("לעלא" refers back to the verbs at the start of the sentence.)
3. *([suggested](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14877) by [Shmuel Brill](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/732))* "May the name of the holy one (blessed be he, who is beyond all blessings, songs, etc.) be blessed, praised, etc." ("לעלא" refers back to "קודשא".)
4. "May the name of the holy one (blessed be he) (which is beyond all blessings, songs, etc.) be blessed, praised, etc." ("לעלא" refers back to "שמה".)

Sources, please.

Comment: (I've always assumed it was #1 or #2, but then Shmuel Brill suggested #3 in his post (linked to in the question), which made me think also of #4.)

Comment: very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7873/759

Comment: Please also consider that le'eila (higher) goes back to viyitaleh (raise up) for those who do not have veyithalal in their nussach (like the Gra).

Comment: Also consider that yitbarach may be part of the preceding phrase (yehei shmeiH...almaya yitbarach.)

Comment: The only plausible ways I can see it are #2 (which I referenced in that answer) or possibly #1 if I'm understanding it correctly, which I'm not too sure. I'm thinking, "May blessed, praised, lauded....be the name of the Holy One (Blessed be He above all other blessings...)" meaning that we are slightly going off on an extended version of "HaKadosh Baruch Hu", after we have blessed His name to the highest levels we can.  I just can't see how the grammar works any other way other than those 2 possibilities.

Comment: @SethJ, yes, that's what I meant by #1.

Answer (score 1):

Curiouser's answer to this question [What should be said after "sh'mei d'kudsha, brich hu" in Kaddish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/what-should-be-said-after-shmei-dkudsha-brich-hu-in-kaddish) brings the Aruch HaShulchan on the parsing.